# Is cblas_dgemm a multithread function?

Tags: c, x86-64, cpu, matrix-multiplication, blas

I have run a simple `cblas_dgemm` example to multiply two matrices and tested that on two different CPUs.

Intel Core i5-6600 which has 4 cores and 1 thread per core.

```
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz
```

AMD Ryzen 7 3700X which has 8 cores and 2 threads per core.

```
CPU(s):                          16
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-15
Thread(s) per core:              2
Model name:                      AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
```

I have noticed that when I run the code on the Ryzen processor, the CPU utilization is 1600% but on the Intel processor it is 100%. The code is available [here](https://pastebin.com/Mkn383G7) and the build commands are

```
gcc -O3 -fsplit-stack -fopenmp -c mm_double_blas.c -o mm_double_blas.o
g++ -std=c++11 -o  mm_double_blas mm_double_blas.o -lblas -fopenmp
```

I have to say that I used openmp header just to use `omp_get_wtime()` to get the time. Any thoughts about the Intel CPU that doesn't utilize all cores? I expect to see 400% utilization.

Comment: Do you have the same BLAS library installed on both machines?  If not, maybe only one of them is a multi-threaded implementation.  (BLAS is an API; there are many implementations.)  Are they both running Linux, so 100% means all of one core?

Comment: Right. Apparently, on the system with runs multithread I see `libopenblas-pthread-dev` and `libopenblas-dev` but the single thread system has `libblas-dev`. I installed openblas packages and now the 4 core system runs multithreaded. Thanks for the hint.